# Why would a 1-in-a-billion years event happening be suprising if it happens once?

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems

Okay, a bit of a background where this question is coming from. I just watched this video ["How lucky is too lucky"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ko3TdPy0TU) which delves into the recent Minecraft speedrun controversy.

Now, the probability of some event happening was determined to be extremely unlikely, and to put that into perspective it was put into terms of "how many years would all the population in the world have to do the task every second for it to be plausible to happen". Let's say this number turns out to be a million-billion years.

So, if that event happens today, should I be surprised/doubtful? It had good chance of happening in a million-billion years, and maybe that time period starts from now. If it happens again within this time period, then yes, I would be surprised/doubtful. I don't understand why some event being extremely unlikely would be a valid argument against it being done fairly without external influences, if it happened only once.

Note: I am not too invested in this controversy apart from the math. I am mentioning it here only to give a good reference and some background on where my question is coming from.

Comment: I think if you flip a (fair) coin $100$ times today, and get heads every time, then you have every right to be surprised.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah, maybe "surprised" wasn't the best word for me to use. I am thinking more about the validity of it being an statistical evidence against something (the coin being unfair in this case). I would think that in a google tries there a good chance of getting 100 heads consecutively, maybe that happened to be the first 100 tries of mine. Now, if I got 100 heads again that would make be suspicious. (But I can extend the argument to n heads in a row, this is what bothers me)

Comment: I think you need to calibrate the "tiny probabilities" with "number of occurences". Suppose instead it had a probability of occuring once in $\sqrt{\text{million-billion}}$ years. Now if you had two independent trials ("two coin flips"), and both happened, you should be pretty much just as surprised as if you witnessed an event with probability $\frac1{\sqrt{\text{million-billion}}} \times \frac1{\sqrt{\text{million-billion}}}=\frac1{\text{million-billion}}$

Comment: By the same reasoning, it shouldn't make you *more* suspicious to get it twice in a row.  If @GerryMyerson had said "50 times" instead of a hundred times, and you said, "well, I wouldn't expect that to happen twice", well, 100 times is it happening twice.

Comment: @johnnyb The increase in number of consecutive heads considered (50->100) would end up increasing the time-period for which I would be suspicious if it were to happen within again.

Comment: But, again, let's say that the original suggestion was "50 heads".  Okay, well, when are you suprised if you get 50 heads again?  Because getting 100 heads would be "getting 50 heads" and then "getting 50 heads again".

Comment: Not a mathematical answer, but I would say the important consideration is whether it is likely _compared to the alternative_. The chance of getting a "one-in-a-zillion" RNG (if I understand the context correctly) is indeed very slim, but more importantly, it is very slim in comparison to the probability the speedrunner cheated. So without any further verification, you would, prima facie, believe it more likely that they cheated. Cf. the 5-sigma standard in particle physics. That is the point at which they decide that their measurement is _more likely than_ random error.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I was thinking about what you said about taking the "number of occurrences" into account. So when the event happening goes from 1-in-a-million to 1-in-a-billion, it also increasing the number of "year" slots it could happen in. Then the chance of it happening in the first year itself would go down! I understand this, but somehow when I think of something happening once as a statistical evidence it seems unreasonable.

Comment: What I mean is, when you said you would be surprised by it happening twice, but not when it happens once, that means you're roughly saying that somehow 1 in (million-billion)${}^2$ **is** surprising, but 1 in million-billion is **not**. For this to be true, I would need the threshold for surprise to be between million-billion and (million-billion)${}^2$. That's not where I would put it, personally.